# Which Questions Should I Answer?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, answers, experts

Non-serious version: I have an answer, I just can't find the right question ;-)

Serious version:

I've asked about 50-60 questions (mostly on StackOverflow). They were, for the most part, good questions that inspired excellent answers. I'm a somewhat intelligent long-time PhD student in computer science (well studied, well published, etc), so I feel that there are probably one or two questions (maybe even three) that I can help answering.

What process do you recommend that a question-only user go through to become a question-and-answer user? For example, I'm fairly well versed in C++. Should I monitor the C++ tag until I see questions that I can research and answer pretty well, or should I be hunting more specifically for questions that I'm already an expert on. Of course, I'm really only an expert on very specific areas of artificial intelligence and ad-hoc wireless networks, so I might have to search long and hard and probably on [cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Hopefully this question is not too broad / trivial. I really respect and appreciate the SO community, and would like to do whatever I can to help it grow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please start by looking through the [Unanswered C++ questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++).  Starting at the top of the unanswered questions in a particular tag usually guarantees that you'll be looking at higher quality and more difficult questions.

Beyond that, you'll also want to add other tags to your interesting list so that you don't miss the few questions that come through in narrower topics.  If they're extremely narrow, you can follow the RSS feed and still probably be the first to answer.

Answer (score 2):

you could ask your question and then answer it yourself (it's allowed!), there will likely be limitations if you want a favorable outcome, because no-one likes a clever *** .. but if your answer is good enough it should be OK over time

but to answer your original post question:

### Which Questions Should I Answer?

any and all. whatever you feel you can